# How to solve this select query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my MySQL Database. The one stores an amount for a month in a year for one specific channel. I have a few channels that are defined in another table. 
Here are the two tables with example data:

```
Table income:
ID | Year | Month | amount | channelID 
    example:
1  | 2017 | 05    | 7.13   | 1
2  | 2017 | 05    | 12.03  | 2
3  | 2017 | 06    | 1.56   | 1
4  | 2017 | 06    | 0.30   | 2


Table channel: 
ID | title            | url
example:
1  | Affiliate Site 1 | http://url1.tld
2  | Affiliate Site 2 | http://url2.tld
```

Now I want to generate a query that gives me an output like this:

```
Expected Output:
Year | Month | amount ch1 | amount ch2
example: 
2017 | 05    | 7.13       | 12.03
2017 | 06    | 1.56       | 0.30
```

I have a basic understanding of writing mysql queries but i cannot solve this thing. I thought about joining the tables together but this would not be the solution. 
How can I combine two (later more) rows of one table that are identified by the Month and the Year in one output row?

Comment: _I thought about joining the tables together but this would not be the solution._ Have you tried it to get the prove?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Where's your query?

Comment: If you're enjoying those links, you may also enjoy: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

A query that would return what you asked:

```
SELECT `Year`
, `Month`
, SUM(IF(`channelID` = 1, `amount`, 0)) 'amount ch1'
, SUM(IF(`channelID` = 2, `amount`, 0)) 'amount ch2'
FROM `income`
GROUP BY `Year`, `Month`;
```

A script that would return the same as the above for an arbitrary number of channels:

```
SET @query = (
    SELECT
        CONCAT(
            'SELECT `Year`' ,
            ', `Month`',
            GROUP_CONCAT(
                ', SUM(IF(`channelID` = ', `id`, ', `amount`, 0)) `amount ch', `id`, '` '
                SEPARATOR ''
            ),
            'FROM `income` ',
            'GROUP BY `Year`, `Month`'
        )
    FROM `channel`
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;

EXECUTE stmt;
```

The above is generating a query based on the data in the channel table and storing it in the `@query` variable. Then preparing a statement with this query and executing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try need to use group by channelid and order by amount.